# Spark returns Empty DataFrame but Populated in Hive

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have a table in hive

```
db.table_name
```

When I run the following in hive I get results back

```
SELECT * FROM db.table_name;
```

When I run the following in a spark-shell

```
spark.read.table("db.table_name").show
```

It shows nothing. Similarly

```
sql("SELECT * FROM db.table_name").show
```

Also shows nothing. Selecting arbitrary columns out before the show also displays nothing. Performing a count states the table has 0 rows.

Running the same queries works against other tables in the same database.

Spark Version: 2.2.0.cloudera1

The table is created using

```
table.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).saveAsTable("db.table_name")
```

And if I read the file using the parquet files directly it works.

```
spark.read.parquet(<path-to-files>).show
```

EDIT:
I'm currently using a workaround by describing the table and getting the location and using spark.read.parquet.

Comment: Are you using HiveContext (if Spark 1.6) or have you called `.enableHiveSupport()` (if Spark 2.x)?

Comment: Using spark2-shell which I believe enables hive support on when setting up the session.

Comment: Are logs available? Have you looked there for possible errors/warnings?

Comment: Since it's client mode all errors/warnings are logged to the shell. No logs get displayed.

Comment: Maybe you can get logs from Spark UI or a Resource Manager?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. No Logs were being produced. I changed the loglevel of org.apache.spark package to DEBUG and ran the same command. 280 lines of logs were produced however I can't pick out any relevent ones since it all just seems to be BatchResolution and code generation logs. Note that the dataframe produced from doing the spar.read.table command has the correct columns and datatypes.

Comment: Could you add logs output to the question, please?

Comment: Didn't know the correct way to add logs that large. https://pastebin.com/VWB4KtXB

Answer (score 0):

Have you refresh metadata table? Maybe you need to refresh table to access to new data.

```
spark.catalog.refreshTable("my_table")
```

Comment: This doesn't help, it still produces the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using

```
query_result.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).format("hive").saveAsTable("table")
```

which stores the results in textfile.
There is probably some incompatibility with the Hive parquet.

I also found a Cloudera report about it ([CDH Release Notes](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/release-notes/topics/cdh_rn_spark_ki.html#ki_sparksql_dataframe_saveastable)): they recommend creating the Hive table manually and then load data from a temporary table or by query.